# What inputs do I have in Optifine shaders?

Tags: glsl, shader, minecraft

Recently I started learning GLSL in the context of Minecraft shaders compatible with Optifine, and I encountered some troubles with them.
What information about the game's world can I use in my shaders code and how can I get it?
For example, the simplest shader that I found online uses variables
`varying vec4 texcoord;`
`uniform sampler2D gcolor;`
that appears to be defined by the standard Minecraft rendering engine, and I wonder which else variables I can use that Optifine provides me?
Thank you in advance for your answers.

Comment: [Read the doc :)](https://github.com/sp614x/optifine/blob/master/OptiFineDoc/doc/shaders.txt)

Comment: https://github.com/sp614x/optifine/blob/master/OptiFineDoc/doc/shaders.txt this is full documentation of optifine shaders.